# I created a LinkedList and i am trying to remove the element . it removes the element only onces rather than all element that machtes with it

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Node {
    public :
        int val;
        Node* next;

        Node(int data) {
            this -> val = data;
            this -> next = NULL;
        }
};


void insertAtTail(Node* &tail, int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    tail -> next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

void print (Node* head) {
    while(head != NULL) {
        cout << head -> val << " ";
        head = head -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Node* removeElement(Node* head, int val) {
    if(head -> val == val) {
        while(head -> val == val) {
            head = head -> next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    else {
        Node* prev = NULL;
        Node* curr = head;
        while(curr -> next != NULL) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
            if(curr -> val == val) {
                prev -> next = curr -> next;
            }
            //cout << prev -> val << " ";  
        }
        
    return head;
    }
}
int main () {
    Node* node1 = new Node(1);
    Node* head = node1;
    Node* tail = node1;

    insertAtTail(tail, 1);
    insertAtTail(tail, 1);
    insertAtTail(tail, 3);
    insertAtTail(tail, 3);
    insertAtTail(tail, 5);
    
    print(removeElement(head, 3));
}
```

1. **problem -**

In this i have passed element to tail in linkedlist and then i am trying to remove specifc element using **removeElement()** what it does it removes only one element that is matched and leaving the other remaing matching element

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Bcp.png)

I want to remove all the element its matches.

Comment: your interpretation is not right. Your code does not "remove only one element" but it does leave one element in. see here: https://godbolt.org/z/4xc56bT13. You should use a debugger to see what actually happens and why

Comment: btw thats why it is important to include actual and expected output in the question rather than only interpretation of it, because that is very likely off

Comment: you are leaking quite a lot of memory

Comment: Where is the list (class) I only see nodes

Comment: If the value is at the head you just remove all subsequent ones with equal value. However you need to continue iteration afterwards, as after finding the same value at the head it might still reside yet another time afterwards, e.g. removing 7 from 7 -> 8 -> 7!

Comment: Off-topic: Get used to implement the constructor initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`); the `Node`'s ctor should look like `Node(int data) : val(data), next(nullptr) {}` which prefers direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + assignment, the latter *potentially* producing (on complex types) significant performance overhead. Additionally some types (references, const members, non-default constructable types) *only* can be initialised that way. And you absolutely should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: You produce memory leaks for not `delete`ing the notes you remove from the list – and those nodes you do *not* remove from the list leak as well, you do not `delete` them either before returning from `main`. Good advice: With *every* `new` consider the corresponding `delete` right at the same time or even before; even better: skip manual memory management entirely and rely on smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`) instead (though a bit uncomfortable with linked lists, admitted).

Comment: `removeElement` is an unlucky name, by the way, if it should remove *multiple* elements – better name it so then: `removeElements` (note the plural s)...

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks... i got it where i did i go wrong .

Comment: Adding to @PepijnKramer: You should re-consider your design. Your linked lists only consist of nodes, and you expose these publicly (C-style like) – allowing *anybody* to break the code (one might want to cut off the tail manually, i.e. not relying on *your* functions, and forget to set the tail's `next` pointer to `nullptr`). Profit from what C++ offers, have a separate class `LinkedList` wrapping around the nodes and hiding these away (or only expose parts of, e.g. the `next` pointer might get private with `LinkedList` being friend to be able to still modify).

Comment: If you "want to remove all the element its matches", then you need to write the code that does it. You've clearly written a function that removes the first value only, so that's what it does. We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow, we only answer questions. You must try to do this yourself, first. One reason you're stumped is because the existing code is about three times more complicated than it needs to be. There's no reason why different code is needed for the head element, and all others. That's wrong. With the right logic, adjusting it to remove all nodes would be trivial.

Comment: As a hint: you can use *double* indirection (`Node**` pointer) to avoid having to make a difference between head and other nodes; this pointer would be set either to `head` or to a `next` pointer – which ever it is, though, you wouldn't need to care for once initially set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing beats drawing.
You should use pen(cil) and paper, but here is an ASCII version of what you're doing:

```
 p is null
 
head->1->1->3->3->5
 ^
 c

prev = curr;

 p
 v
head->1->1->3->3->5
 ^
 c

curr = curr->next

 p
 v
head->1->1->3->3->5
      ^
      c

prev = curr;

      p
      v
head->1->1->3->3->5
      ^
      c

curr = curr->next

      p
      v
head->1->1->3->3->5
         ^
         c

prev = curr;

         p
         v
head->1->1->3->3->5
         ^
         c

curr = curr->next

         p
         v
head->1->1->3->3->5
            ^
            c

if(curr -> val == val) {
    prev -> next = curr -> next;
}

         p +----+
         v |    v
head->1->1-+ 3->3->5
             ^
             c 

(Note that this detaches 'curr' from the list.)             

prev = curr;

           +----+
           |    v
head->1->1-+ 3->3->5
             ^
             c
             p

(And 'prev' now points to the detached node.)

curr = curr->next

           +----+
           |    v
head->1->1-+ 3->3->5
             ^  ^
             p  c



if(curr -> val == val) {
    prev -> next = curr -> next;
}

           +-------+
           |       v
head->1->1-+ 3-+   3->5
             ^ |   ^  ^
             p |   c  |
               |      |
               +------+

(And this sets the 'next' pointer of a node that is no longer part of the list.)

prev = curr;

           +-------+
           |       v
head->1->1-+ 3-+   3->5
               |   ^  ^
               |   c  |
               |   p  |
               +------+

curr = curr->next


           +-------+  c
           |       v  v
head->1->1-+ 3-+   3->5
               |   ^  ^
               |   p  |
               |      |
               +------+

and curr->next is null.

Result:

           +-------+   
           |       v   
head->1->1-+       3->5
```

Now use pen(cil) and paper and work out what the code *should* do, and then translate that into code.
(Hint: you need to do different things depending on whether you remove a node or not.)

Comment: thanks a lot... i will always try pen(cil) and paper.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation has some issues and will not work for many test cases. However, there is at least one major problem in the second while loop of the removeElement. I tried to solve it with minimal modifications for the specific test that you sent.

Replace it with the following code:

```
while(curr -> next != NULL) {
  if(curr -> val == val) {
    prev -> next = curr -> next;
    curr = prev -> next;
  }
  else {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr -> next;
  }
  //cout << prev -> val << " ";  
}
```

Comment: For completeness: On dropping the current node it would be a good idea to already `delete curr;` before setting it to `prev->next` ...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of how you should deal with this depends on your real goal in writing the code. If you're planning to put this to real use, you probably don't want to write any of this. The standard library already has code for linked lists, and absent a reason to do otherwise, you normally want to use that.

```cpp
    // intersperse '1' with other elements:
    std::forward_list<int> ints { 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1 };

    // remove all the '1' elements:
    ints.remove(1);

    // print out the result:
    std::copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Result:

```
3 3 5
```

No muss, no fuss, no memory leaks. Better still, this is fairly easy to convert to (for example) an `std::vector`, since linked lists are only rarely a good idea anyway.

If this is for homework (or something like that) where implementing the linked list yourself is the whole point of the exercise, I'd start by wrapping the linked list up as a class with a few member functions, and the `node` hidden inside:

```cpp
class list {

    class node {
        int value;
        node *next = nullptr;

        node(int value, node *next = nullptr) : value(value), next(next) {}
    };

    node *head;
    node *tail;

public:

    void insertHead(int newValue);
    void insertTail(int newValue);
    bool remove(int oldValue);
    void print() const;
};
```